# How to remove static block in default_head.xml file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, static-block

First of all I am adding a template file in default_head.xml file.
In Template file i am calling a block using idetifier.
Now I want to remove block 
In defaul_head.xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="ves.wizz">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Magento_Theme::html/wiz.phtml</argument>
   </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="ves.wizz" remove="true" />
```

Comment: I saw in your content defaul_head.xml file: if you want remove `ves.wizz` block you only put this content : `<referenceBlock name="ves.wizz" remove="true" />`

Comment: delete : `<referenceBlock name="ves.wizz">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Magento_Theme::html/wiz.phtml</argument>
   </arguments>
</referenceBlock>`

Comment: Note: after change layout file, you have to clear cache by this command: `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Firstly I am trying this code but not respond